# Receiving full date time in node API instead of receiving date only

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to get only date pate part from timestamp value using `DATE()` in MySQL its showing result correct in MySQL but in node js its showing full-time stamp instead of date.

Example : -

```
SELECT DATE("2020-04-12T18:30:00.000Z");
```

Generating `2020-04-12` in MySQL but in node js while fetching through my own API it's giving `"2020-04-12T18:30:00.000Z"` this.

Help me to Solve this.

Comment: I don't want to use any extra library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in the query SQL this:

```sql
SELECT ...,(DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%Y-%m-%d") as finalDate) FROM ...
```

And now in your API, when you call to MySQL with the previous query you should have `2017-06-15` in `finalDate`. The type DATE in MySQL is a Date Object, so if you want only date in string, you need to cast it in MySQL with the previous code or in your API with parsing date to string with methods or `Date`

Comment: Thank You this solution also worked for me. but the issue is with me because of MySQL package in Node JS this can also be solved by adding ```dateString=true```  in database config of app.js I found this solution.